# Re render in Vue3 - how to update component when store value changes

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, pinia

I am using the pinia store and I need to update a component in realtime. The variable `num1` will be changing value from another component and I need to display the change in this component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ num1 }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useCalcStore } from '@/store/store'

export default {
  name: 'screenCalculator',

  setup(){
    const store = useCalcStore();
    

    const reload = () => {
      let num1 = store.getNumber1;
      return num1
    }
    return {reload}
  }
}
</script>
```

I have tried to use the keys and `forceUpdate` but I haven't succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading from a store should not be done in a `reload` function.
The whole point of using stores is: they hold reactive data in `state` or `getters` (derived state), shared across all components importing them.

Whenever this data changes, all components receive the change, and update *automatically*.

In a nutshell, that's what ***reactivity*** means: realtime self-updating data.

---

Your current syntax:

```
let num1 = store.getNumber1 // ❌ not reactive
```

...breaks reactivity, while using any of the following alternative syntaxes maintains it:

```js
const num1 = storeToRefs(store).getNumber1 // ✅ reactive
```

```js
const { getNumber1: num1 } = storeToRefs(store) // ✅ reactive
```

```js
const num1 = computed(() => store.getNumber1) // ✅ reactive
```

`num1` is now a [ref()](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) which can be used in `template` and will reflect any change in `store.getNumber1`'s value.
If you need its value inside `<script>`, use `num1.value`, like with any other ref.

---

Complete example (I skipped creating `const`s for `store` and `num1`, since they're only used once, but `setup` does return a `num1` ref for `<template>`, pointing to `store.getNumber1`):

```html
<template>
  <p>{{ num1 }}</p>
</template>

<script>
import { useCalcStore } from '@/store/store'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'

export default {
  name: 'screenCalculator',
  setup: () => ({
    num1: storeToRefs(useCalcStore()).getNumber1
  })
}
</script>
```

---

**Important note**: `storeToRefs` only returns reactive store members (`state` and `getters`).
`actions` can be obtained from the store itself:

```
const { action1, action2 } = useSomeStore()
```

Comment: Very important & good code explanation for reactive state for pinia, Thank's a lot :)